# Salesforce 2018 Summer Release, The Utility Bar will be floated at the top @Newest Version of 2018 Edge

Tags: lightning-apps, utility-bar, microsoft-edge

1. I had ever created a Lightning App
2. My Developer Org has been upgraded to Salesforce 2018 Summer Release
3. I Login My Org Using Chrome Browser, It works fine.(**I can see Utility Bar at the Bottom of Lightning.**)
4. I Login My Org Using the Newest Version of Edge, **The Utility will be floated at the top.**
   [
   Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
   Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134
   @2018 Microsoft
   ]

**Dose anyone know why utility bar is floated at the top?
Is there any solution to resolve this?**
[image]

The Bug is attatched by The below screenshot

Comment: I have edited My Post, Could you please take a look at this issue ?